# Flutter filter box (iPhone style)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

How to create a filter box or buttons in Flutter? (I don't know the right name)
On iPhones this would look something like this:
[image]

When the user clicks on an option it turns white (comes to the forground) and the list is filtered.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Cupertino widgets. The one you show is called a [`CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html) widget. For future reference, Flutter maintains a catalog of widgets. The Cupertino widgets can be found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino).

Comment: Thanks for replying! Does this work on Android too?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes. Flutter does it's own rendering. Widgets are not platform-dependent.

Comment: @Heisenberg Please mark this answer as accepted if it helped.